# Complex Solutions to Polynomial Equations

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have to find another complex solution to the polynomial equation $z^6 - 1 = 0$ given that $\frac{1}{2}−\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ is a solution.

I guess the question I have for this is that is there any other way other than expanding the brackets out completely?

Comment: Since the coefficients of the polynomial are real, the complex conjugate must also be a solution

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thats the question word for word

Comment: @DavidQuinn so $1/2 - \sqrt{3}/2$ would be another solution...?

Comment: Your first root is missing the factor $i$. The comjugate is $\frac 12-i\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had to give another complex soltuion, and yes I forgot the I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
the roots are as follows
$$x_1=1$$
$$x_2=-1$$
roots of $x^2+x+1$ are
$$x_{3,4}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$
roots of $x^2-x+1$ are
$$x_{5,6}=\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by the roots of $x^2 + x + 1$

Comment: roots of second degree eqution

Comment: You might want to include the solutions $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Hrhm thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 6 solutions to this equation, called the sixth roots of unity.

They are as follows:

$$e^0=1$$
$$e^{i(\pi/3)}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$e^{i(2\pi/3)}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
$$e^{i(4\pi/3)}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$e^{i(5\pi/3)}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
These solutions form a hexagon in the plane. 
How can we derive these solutions?

The first thing to note is that modulus is multiplicative. So, we have the following equation: 
$$\left|z^6\right|=\left|z\right|^6=1$$
From this we conclude that $\left|z\right|=1$.

Next, note that when you multiply two complex numbers, you add their arguments. So, if $\theta$ is the argument of $z$, we have the following equation: 
$$6\theta=2k\pi \text{ for some integer } k$$

Using these two equations, you can get the six answers mentioned above.